# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a weird exception that I cannot reproduce (come from bugsense):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
at java.util.HashMap.addNewEntry(HashMap.java:476)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:408)
```

How come put method on `ConcurrentHashMap` can throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ? 
(I tried also to use ConcurrentHashMap but without any luck)

any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Adding code:

```
final Map<String, DataSource> dataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSource>();
public void setDataSource(@Nonnull String field, @Nullable DataSource source) {
    // concurrent hash map doesnt allow null values
    if (field != null) {
        if (source != null) {
            dataSources.put(field, source);
        } else {
            dataSources.remove(field);
        }
    }
}
```

Many threads call this method simultaneously

Thanks.

Comment: What's the associated code?

Comment: Do you have several threads accessing the map?
If so, there could be a potential problem coming from the backing array being resized by one thread while an other thread tries to put a new entry.

Comment: Yeah there are several threads over there, but I tried also using `ConcurrentHashMap` but without any luck.

Comment: Readers please note that the stacktrace does not match the code that the OP added later.  This is NOT evidence of a problem in `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stacktrace show that you are using the [Android version of HashMap](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master%5E2/luni/src/main/java/java/util/HashMap.java).

My diagnosis is that you've somehow managed to get a corrupt `HashMap` object.  The `addNewEntry` method is indexing the main hash array (`table`), but the length of the array is (apparently) zero.  This is something that should never happen ... and (I think) it can only happen if the capacity calculation goes wrong when expanding the array.  (Check how the code handles an empty map ...)

It is *possible* (I guess) that you've encountered a bug in the `HashMap` implementation in the version of Android you are using.  However I think it is *far more likely* that the corruption is due to your application using / updating the map object using multiple threads without proper synchronization.  I recommend that you explore that theory first; i.e. check your synchronization.

---

I don't know why the updated question is talking about `ConcurrentHashMap`.  The evidence in stacktrace *clearly* shows that the problem occurred with `HashMap`.  I'm only prepared to offer a diagnosis based on actual evidence that I can see.

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap` for synchronization the map is not enough?

Comment: I'd have thought it would be.  But to be honest, I'd like to see an SSCCE before I made a judgement on that.

Comment: The code you added show you using `ConcurrentHashMap`.  But the failure occurred when you were using `HashMap` (and you said that you couldn't reproduce it!).  Is the failure reproducible?  Does it happen with the updated version?  Where is the stacktrace for that?  What version of Android are you actually using?  (Can you provide a link to the source code of the exact version of that class???)